# Randomly selecting from mysql but not twice

Tags: php, mysql

Like the title asks. What I'm trying to do is where I have a list of entries sorted by a auto incrementing ID int. I have around 1 thousand and I want to be able to pick 200 randomly or even 50 random ones but they cannot be twice picked in the same list of 200 or 50. How can I manage to do this in mysql.

Comment: Order them randomly and select 200

Comment: Do it in MySQL. Order by rand() and limit 200 (or whatever amount you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order the results in MySQL by `rand()` and limit the number you want. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 200
```